# Identify adjacent and no-adjacent polygons between multiple shapefiles using R?

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, proximity

My spatial data are recorded multiple years, providing one polygon for a year. (Polygon is derived from raster data, so I can use  rasters instead if it will be easier to run my calculations).

I start with year t1. Next year, I add my t2 shapefile. **I want to know, which of my t2 polygons are adjacent to t1 year and which are not?** for t3, which polygon are adjacent to t1 or t2, and which are not?

[image]

I think it can be done by some type of proximity analysis, but I can't really figure out which one. My expected results is a table containing the information if the certain polygon is adjacent to any of the polygons from the previous year (TRUE, FALSE) and what is the area of the polygon per year.

here are some dummy data: https://uloz.to/x8o66ow8/t1-poly-zip

I prefer to use R, but I can also use ArcGIS. I'm not python experienced user.

---

I think, that one of the solutions could be:

1. calculate area of all year (t1, t2, t3)
2. merge and dissolve t1 + t2
3. calculate area of polygons which are not merged with t1 and distract
   this area from the total area of t2
4. merge and dissolve t1 + t2 + t3
5. calculate area of polygons which are not merged with t1 + t2 and
   distract this area from the total area of t3
6. etc..

but I hope to automate the process..

Comment: If you do not get any answers using R, then I think you should change your question to ArcGIS for Desktop, or research/ask about that separately.

Comment: When you say "adjacent" what exactly do you mean? Touching, within a specified distance, nearest? These would all require different approaches so, please be specific.

Comment: Ideally touching, but can be within i.e. a certain buffer zones.

Comment: That file doesn't look like something I want to download. Can you post code to reproduce the objects?